# Systemd with rtorrent in tmux

Tags: tmux, systemd

I have been unable to get tmux & rtorrent running with a systemd service file. My `rtorrent.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=rTorrent
Documentation=https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent
After=network.target local-fs.target

[Service]
Type=forking
KillMode=none
User=rtorrent
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux -S /tmp/rtorrent.sock new-session -d -s rtorrent \'rtorrent -n -O import=/etc/rtorrent.rc\'
ExecStop=/usr/bin/tmux -S /tmp/rtorrent.sock send-keys -t rtorrent C-q
WorkingDirectory=/home/rtorrent

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

(Using `Type=oneshot` with `RemainAfterExit=yes` did not work, and I'm not convinced that is a solution anyway. I think running `tmux` this way ought to be done with `Type=forking`. Please correct me if I'm wrong!)

The output from `systemctl status rtorrent`:

```
● rtorrent.service - rTorrent
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/rtorrent.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2015-04-27 10:48:37 AEST; 22s ago
     Docs: https://github.com/rakshasa/rtorrent
  Process: 4433 ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux -S /tmp/rtorrent.sock new-session -d -s rtorrent 'rtorrent -n -O import=/etc/rtorrent/rtorrent.rc' (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Apr 27 10:48:37 vagrant tmux[4433]: usage: new-session [-AdDP] [-c start-directory] [-F format] [-n window-name] [-s session-name] [-t target-session] [-x width] [-y height] [command]
Apr 27 10:48:37 vagrant systemd[1]: rtorrent.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Apr 27 10:48:37 vagrant systemd[1]: Failed to start rTorrent.
Apr 27 10:48:37 vagrant systemd[1]: Unit rtorrent.service entered failed state.
```

Switching to the `rtorrent` user with `su` allows me to try the `ExecStart` command manually - which works fine. I'm at a loss to debug this further.

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you starting it in tmux?

Comment: You probably shouldn't be escaping the quotes - you are trying to pass that as a single argument to `tmux`, so just use quotes as you normally would.

Comment: @jordanm not really sure how that is relevant

Comment: @muru that fixed it - at one point I was getting errors which I thought I fixed with the escaping.. oh well. Add an answer to claim your points

Answer (score 4, accepted):

systemd does its own interpretation of values of `Exec` and other keys. Therefore, you shouldn't write as if this is going to be passed to `sh -c` or something like that. In particular, if you want to treat a set of words as a single argument, quote it as you normally would, and don't escape the quotes. Consider this example from [the systemd docs](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html):

> Example:
>
> ```
> ExecStart=/bin/echo one ; /bin/echo "two two"
> ```
>
> This will execute `/bin/echo` two times, each time with one argument:
>   `one` and `two two`, respectively. Because two commands are specified,
>   `Type=oneshot` must be used.

So the `ExecStart` line should be:

```
ExecStart=/usr/bin/tmux -S /tmp/rtorrent.sock new-session -d -s rtorrent 'rtorrent -n -O import=/etc/rtorrent.rc'
```